# initialize double click on edit control in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to set an mouse click event on editbox and when I am double clicking on edit box it should bring up a message box.

```
ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK(IDC_EDITItem, &MessageManage::OnItemDoubleClick)

void MessageManage::OnItemDoubleClick()
{
    MessageBox( m_strItemMsg, "Sample code", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION );
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble doing?

Comment: It's not taking double click event from edit box

Comment: You cannot invent a function signature, and hope that everything works out right. The function signature for `ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` is [`afx_msg void OnLButtonDblClk( UINT nFlags, CPoint point )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3efhe03w.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

At alternative is to just use [`PreTranslateMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2.aspx) on your dialog:

```
BOOL CMFCApplication1Dlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK &&
        pMsg->hwnd == ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_EDIT1))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Run Code"));
        return TRUE; //Important!!! Message is handled
    }

    return CDialogEx::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> It's not taking double click event from edit box

One way to accomplish this is to derive your own class from CEdit and handle `ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK()`.  The following code responded to the double click on an edit control in a sample program.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// MyEdit message handlers

void MyEdit::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    CEdit::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: Most elegant solution !